# Why is java.util.Date's setTime() method not deprecated?

Tags: java, date, time, calendar, deprecated

All the other mutators got deprecated back in JDK 1.1, so why was `setTime()` left as is?  Surely `java.util.Calendar` - the correct way to manipulate dates - can create new instances of `java.util.Date` as needed using the `java.util.Date(long)` constructor?

Comment: I really wish that Date was immutable.

Comment: You don't have to use it, you know. There are better alternatives.

Comment: @skaffman. Not if you are using to java.sql.*. Making java.sql.Timestamp a subclass of java.util.Date was another horrible mistake, of course.

Comment: When you're using `java.sql` date classes, you can limit the use of them to local variables, which at least limits their general awfulness to a small piece of private code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bits of `Date` that were deprecated were those bits that related to calendars (i.e. day, month, year, etc). You'll note that the accessor methods for calendar fields are also deprecated, not just the mutators.

The representation as a milliseconds value, however, is still the way `Date` works, and is unrelated to the calendar representation, so it stayed as undeprecated.

Answer (score 4):

The other mutators were trying to use `java.util.Date` as a calendar, rather than as an instant in time, wrapping a number of milliseconds since Jan 1st 1970 12am UTC. As such, it makes sense for that one mutator not to be deprecated.

The `Date`/`Calendar` APIs are still terrible of course, and you should still use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) wherever possible - but I can see why that call wasn't deprecated. You can't make a type immutable after the fact, and that wasn't the point of the deprecation - the point was to try to stop people from using it as storage for "June 19th 1976" etc.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `setTime` method is at least logically correct: the `setX` methods which take *day*, *month* etc make no sense: a java `Date` is an **instant in time** and hence *day*, *hour*, *month* etc relate only to the view of that `Date` in a particular `TimeZone`.